# grub doesn't load grub.cfg automatically

Tags: grub2, grub-efi

Recently had to reinstall Ubuntu. Now everytime I start up, I hit the grub CLI despite setting my grub timeout to zero and whatnot. If I type 
`configfile (hd0,4)/boot/grub/grub.cfg` Ubuntu loads as expected. I've tried `grub-install /dev/sda` but I still hit the CLI every time. How can I fix this?

Comment: Run `sudo update-grub` and report back any error messages or let us know if it fixed it.

Comment: `Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-36-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
`

Comment: Didnt mention but yes update-grub has been running fine the entire time

Comment: Aww you are running EFI. The `grub-install` line changes in that case.

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem found the  solution : 
1) in the grub rescue mode, run “set”

2) It show me prefix=(hd1,gp1)/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/ 
3) In my case, as I have KDE NEON the folder /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/ doesnt exist, but the folder //boot/efi/EFI/neon/  It does exist. SO the problem is that is pointing to an non exsiting folder  
4)So I copied all the folder /boot/efi/EFI/neon/ to /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/ . That did the trick 
IN my case also is wrong   (hd1,gp1) because it shoudl point to hd1,gpt5. But I DINDT changed that and it worked.  
What I changed is the file /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg, for use msdos format:

```
search.fs_uuid xkjdiw-18e9-4d0a-ac55-2skjdh8425f root hd1,gpt5 
set prefix=($root)'/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

Comment: I had the same problem: wrong prefix.

Answer (score 0):

It could be in a bad instalation. Probably a person copied the grub folders from an existing instalation, grub-install must **generates** the folder for you. Having a fresh grub folder, and putting the grub.cfg on it, it is gonna work.

It is very simple process, I saw many websites telling to install grub without the most important parameter!! (--boot-directory=/where/is/mounted):

1- Mount the usb to a desired folder, or get the /media/user/... path generated by plugging it.

2- Use this mount path for **--boot-directory=**/where/is/mounted

3- Pass the device (the root device, no number, ex /dev/sdb or /dev/sdc...) as the last parameter. To discover it, run **sudo fdisk -l** and look for **sdb1 or sdc1** or above letter, if **USB stick**, a letter above B as sdb sdc, because the A letter represents the hard drive, only use it if you are sure about what you are doing and really want to install grub in the main hard disc.

All command to generate /grub folder on the device is:

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/where/is/mounted /dev/sdx
```

**Note:** this method creates a grub folder on the top of device, *without a boot folder* and it works fine. I prefer, less clicks and work fine. If you want the scheme /boot/grub on usb, add */boot* at the end of parameter and grub will mkdir for you:

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/where/is/mounted/boot /dev/sdx
```